# Change <template> (TemplateElement) programmatically

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

Going back to my question [Query elements inside <content> of a custom element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22071232/query-elements-inside-content-of-a-custom-element)

Now I would like to programmatically change the template of the nested custom element before start of rendering. Is it possible?

```dart
<polymer-element name="my-element">
  <template>
  <div>
    <template id="tml" repeat="{{items}}">
     Hi, {{}}! 
    </template>
  </div>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="my_element.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>

<polymer-element name="my-decorator">
  <template>
  <div>
    <div>Decorator</div>
    <content>
      <!-- my-element will be here-->
    </content>
  </div>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="my_decorator.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

in index.html:

```dart
<my-decorator>
  <my-element></my-element>
</my-decorator>
```

in my_decorator.dart:

```dart
@override
void enteredView() {
  super.enteredView();

  ContentElement content = shadowRoot.querySelector('content');
  MyElement elm = content.getDistributedNodes().firstWhere((e) => e is MyElement);

  TemplateElement elm = elm.shadowRoot.querySelector("#tml");
  // TODO
  // change template here!
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you change the template?
In `attached()` after `super.attached()` the element is already rendered.

You can access the template with `this.templateInstance`
and try to change it **before** `super.attached()` (or in the constructor or in polymerCreated).
I haven't done this myself yet.

It's no problem to change the rendered element.
If you want to avoid that the this change is visible, you can set a (CSS) class initially which is defined to render the element invisible and after you are done with your changes, remove this class.

Comment: The reason is in <template id="tml" repeat="{{items}}">. Collection {{items}} is ObservableList and can be changed. So I need to change views for all new items in this list.. It would be simpler to change the template.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you want to change the inner `<template>`. With `templateInstance` you get the outer template. But I still do not understand why you want to change the template. It isn't that what `repeat` is for?